# ASP.NET - Update panel in Master page, refresh button in Content Page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, master-pages, ajax.net, contentplaceholder

I have Update panel in Master page:

```
<asp:ScriptManager id="CartScript" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>       
<asp:UpdatePanel id="CartBox" runat="server" updateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    Košík [ <asp:HyperLink NavigateUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="ShoppingCart" runat="server" text="" /> ] <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteCart" runat="server" Text="Vymazat košík" OnClick="ThrowCart_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and Buy Button in Content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">    
  <asp:Button ID="BuyButton" Runat="server" Text="Přidat do košíku" onclick="Buy_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

So I need add to Update panel AsyncPostBackTrigger for this button.

First i tryed add it from content page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();         
    trigger.ControlID = "BuyButton";  
    UpdatePanel panel = (UpdatePanel)Master.FindControl("CartBox");   
    if (panel != null)  
    {  
        panel.Triggers.Add(trigger);  
    }  
    ScriptManager script = (ScriptManager)Master.FindControl("CartScript");  
    script.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(BuyButton);  
}
```

But it did error: **A control with ID 'BuyButton' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'CartBox'.**

So i tried it add from Master page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
    if ((Button)MainContent.FindControl("BuyButton")!=null)
    {
        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = ((Button)MainContent.FindControl("BuyButton")).ID;
        CartBox.Triggers.Add(trigger);
        CartScript.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl((Button)MainContent.FindControl("BuyButton"));
    }
}
```

But i got same error. :-(

So can u tell me how I can add to my Update Panel that Button from Content Page can refresh it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**

Place the `BuyButton` button inside of its own `UpdatePanel` as well on the content page.  Add your `AsyncPostBackTrigger` to that new `UpdatePanel`, and then it will be able to find the button, and will use the `ScriptManager` from the master page.

Comment: @StackOverflowException: Ah, missed that detail.  Thanks :)